# IMPORTRANGE multiplesheets and give a status

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Im using importrange function to import multiple sheets of USERS to a mastersheet. Say all data imported are from Col A:Z then on Col AA of the mastersheet im giving a status for the each entry(row). but when the users update their data the Col AA on the mastersheet does not sync with the data imported. is there a way to "link" or "pair" the rows imported with the existing sheet rows. I hope you understand what im trying to do.

Comment: Use arrayformula to `AA` column so that it sync automatically.

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are describing how formula results get misaligned with manually entered data. Lance has given a thorough [treatment of the row misalignment issue](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/95901649) and how it can be dealt with in some cases.

It would probably be easiest to update column `AA` in the user sheets instead of the master sheet, and include that column in the imports.